# Java Method to get Average Salary or Javascript

Tags: java, mysql, reactjs, spring-boot, jpa

I have my employee model that has JPA columns defined for the MYSQL db. I have defined my columns for the db, and the constructor. here is how the Employee model looks like:

```
package employeeapps.com.example.EmployeeTracker.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {





    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;


    @Column(name = "company_id")
    private Integer companyId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name= "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name= "salary")
    private Integer salary;

    @Column(name = "email_id")
    private String emailId;


    //Company is one and has many employees
//name represents id of company in company entity and referencedColumnName represents company_id in the employee entity.
//    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Company.class)
//    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="company_id")
//    private Set<Company> company;


    //default constructor
    public Employee(){

    }

    //create a public constructor with the appropriate parameters to be able to create a new instance of an employee
    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String emailId, String address, Integer salary, Integer companyId){
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.address = address;
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    //define methods
    //long data type because could be a very long numerical  data
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long companyId){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmailId(){
        return emailId;
    }
    public void setEmailId(String emailId){
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }
    public void setCompanyId(Integer companyId){
        this.companyId= companyId;
    }
    public Integer getCompanyId(){
        return companyId;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getAddress(){return address;}

    public void setSalary(Integer salary){
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public Integer getSalary(){return salary;}
}
```

employee JPA Repository

```
package employeeapps.com.example.EmployeeTracker.repository;

import employeeapps.com.example.EmployeeTracker.model.Company;
import employeeapps.com.example.EmployeeTracker.model.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


//JPA has methods like ById findbyId FindAll         long is the primary key
@Repository
public interface employeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,  Long>{
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to create a method or function where I can display, in a new column, the average **salary** for the employee table using javascript

Here is how my employeeList looks which fetched the mysql data using axios and setEmployee as the data from my backend.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import EmployeeService from "../service/EmployeeService";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const EmployeeList = () => {
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
EmployeeService.getEmmployees().then((res) => {
    setEmployees(res.data)
})
}, [employees])



const editEmployee = (id) => {
    window.location.assign(`/update-employees/${id}`)
}

const deleteEmployee = (id) => {
    //rest API Call
    EmployeeService.deleteEmployee(id).then((res) => {
        //filter out of the employees array
        employees.filter(employee => employee.id !== employee)
    })
}
  return (
   
    <div className="row">
    
      <h2 className="text-center employee-title"> Employees</h2>
      <div className="add-employee-link">
      <Link to="/add-employees">
       <button> Add Employee</button>
      </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center ">
        <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Company ID</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Employee Email</th>
              <th>Employee Address</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            {employees.map((employee) => (
              <tr key={employee.id}>
                <td>{employee.companyId}</td>
                <td>{employee.firstName}</td>
                <td>{employee.lastName}</td>
                <td>{employee.emailId}</td>
                <td>{employee.address}</td>
                <td>{employee.salary}</td>
               
                <td>
                    <button onClick={() => editEmployee(employee.id)} className="update-btn">Update</button>
                    <button onClick={() => deleteEmployee(employee.id)} className="delete-btn" style={{marginLeft: '2%'}}>Delete</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EmployeeList;
```

Comment: Doesn't the employee table contain individual employees? If so, what should that average salary be? Would it be the same value for _all_ employees in which case putting it into that table would be bad design? Or would it be per employe in which case I'd ask about the difference to `salary`?

Comment: Questions on your skills so far: do you know how to query a JPA repository to read employees? Do you know how to update employees? Do you know how to calculate average values in Java?